# Ethereum wallet does not work with version over geth 1.8.23

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

Ethereum wallet does not work with version over geth 1.8.23
I have geth 1.9.1 installed, I am fully synchronized, but ethereum wallet requires you to download 1.8.23 and does not want to work with geth 1.9.1
How to make ethereum wallet work with geth 1.9.1?
windows 10.

Comment: I think the Ethereum Wallet and Mist have been discontinued, so that's probably why. (Last release is from a year ago: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases)

Comment: It seems you are right, the ethereum wallet is outdated and not supported. I will try MetaMask, I think I managed to connect it to geth 1.9.1. Thank you.